# Induction proof - Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, induction, computer-science

How can you go from $(k+1)k!>(k+1)2^k$ to $(k+1)!>(k+1)2^k$ in induction?
(Assumption: $k!>2^k), k>4$

Why can the LHS get rid of the $k$?

[image]

Comment: When comparing $a_n = n!$ against $b_n = 2^n$, for $n \geq 4$, compute $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ versus $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$.  Then note that $a_{n+1} = a_n \times \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ while $b_{n+1} = b_n \times \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$.

Comment: $(k+1)! = (k+1)k!$ by defininiton of the factoral,  $k! > 2^k$ by the inductive hypothesis. $(k+1)! > (k+1)2^k.$   As $k> 4, k+1 > 2$ so $(k+1)2^k > 2^{k+1}$